# What are models of empty theory?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, model-theory

Consider arbitrary language $\mathcal{L}$, theory $T = \emptyset$ and $A = \{\ \mathcal{M} \mid \mathcal{M} \models T \}$. How does the set $A$ look like?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It consists of all $\mathcal L$-structures. $T$ being empty means the structures don't have to satisfy any additional requirements.